# Adding UITableView to ViewController - Scrolling horizontally

Tags: uitableview, swift, storyboard, horizontal-scrolling

I am fairly new to swift (and xcode) but I was wondering I could add a `UITableView` to an existing `ViewController` (using storyboard) separated in two:

```
UIView1: 100%w, 50%h
UIView2: 100%w, 50%h
```

What I would like is replacing `UIView2` with a `UITableView` and make it scroll horizontally so my cells could be **100%w**, **50%h** (related to `MasterView`)

How should I do that? I saw one [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) but it's not really straight forward and it's not using swift. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a collection view not for a table view. A UICollectionView spreads out the tiles over an area and if the area has only space horizontally it will space all cells after each other like a horizontal table view.